# ¿Cómo hacer una caja con float left y text right?

Tags: css, html5

intento hacer una caja que creo es sencilla, pero no puedo subir el texto para que quede del lado derecho.

Pongo el ejemplo con HTML y CSS y una imagen de como busco que salga. Espero me puedan orientar. Gracias.

```css
    .cajathumbnail {float: left;}
      .cajatitle { font:30px Archivo Black;display:inline-block;margin-bottom:20px;float:right;}
```

```html
    <div class='cajathumbnail'> 
    <figure>
      <a href=''><img src='https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0d/49/11/4b/new-york-by-swift314.jpg'/></a>
      <figcaption class='cajatitle'><a href=''>Título del post a mostrar</a></figcaption>
 
     </figure>
    </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: usas bootstrap, materialize o algún otro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asumiendo que no se pueda cambiar el HTML y que sea necesario usar float, la solución más sencilla sería definir anchos para la imagen y para el contenedor del texto.

```css
.cajathumbnail  figure > a {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}

.cajathumbnail figure > a img {
  width: 100%;
}

.cajatitle {
  font: 30px Archivo Black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class='cajathumbnail'> 
  <figure>
    <a href='#'><img src='https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0d/49/11/4b/new-york-by-swift314.jpg'/></a>
    <figcaption class='cajatitle'><a href=''>Título del post a mostrar</a></figcaption>
 </figure>
</div>
```

Sería más fácil aún la solución con flexbox, definiendo a `<figure>` como el contenedor:

```css
    .cajathumbnail figure {
      display: flex;
    }

    .cajatitle {
      margin-left: 10px;
      font: 30px Archivo Black;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class='cajathumbnail'> 
      <figure>
        <a href='#'><img src='https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0d/49/11/4b/new-york-by-swift314.jpg'/></a>
        <figcaption class='cajatitle'><a href=''>Título del post a mostrar</a></figcaption>
     </figure>
    </div>
```

Comment: Salió mejor con la opción de flexbox que sugeriste. Muchas gracias, Shaz.

Answer (score 0):

Te saldría mucho más fácil hacerlo con flex-box

---

```css
.cajathumbnail{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.cajathumbnail>h1{
  background-color: blueviolet;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='cajathumbnail'> 
        
    <figure>
      <a href=''><img src='https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0d/49/11/4b/new-york-by-swift314.jpg'/></a>
    </figure>
    <h1>Título del post a mostrar</h1>
</div>
```